# firewalld: Significance of the number after INPUT/OUTPUT

Tags: rhel, iptables, firewalld

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter OUTPUT 0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport=80 -j ACCEPT
```

What does the 0 after OUTPUT mean or what is the significance of any number after INPUT/OUTPUT?  I am not finding anything that breaks this down for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

That's priority, it's used to order the rules. From [firewall-cmd manpage](https://firewalld.org/documentation/man-pages/firewall-cmd.html):

> [**--permanent**] **--direct** **--add-rule** { *ipv4* | *ipv6* | *eb* } *table* *chain* *priority* *args*
>
> Add a rule with the arguments *args* to chain *chain* in table *table* with priority *priority*.
>
> The *priority* is used to order rules. Priority 0 means add rule on top of the chain, with a higher priority the rule will be added further down. Rules with the same priority are on the same
> level and the order of these rules is not fixed and may change. If you want to make sure that a rule will be added after another one, use a low priority for the first and a higher for the
> following.